# Does regexp to validate Youtube channel name and link to channel exists?

Tags: regex, validation, youtube, youtube-channels

I'm working with youtube API now, and I'm developing a web application which will help users to find youtube channels (user see a html form and can input link to youtube channel or channel name).

Examples of links to channel:

- `https://www.youtube.com/channel/fhfKH3KHHhjhj`
- `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fhfKH3KHHhjhj`
- and other

Examples of channel names: `asdfasdfs`, `BssdfsdBdsfsdf`, `Dasdasd123`, `Asfdsf Asdfsd`, `asdsa_asd` and other.

**Problem**

Using Regexp, I need to check validness of:

- youtube channel name
- link to youtube channel

Unfortunatelly, I can not find any rules how to validate channel's name or link in [youtube api docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/)

**Question**

How to validate *youtube channel name* and *link to youtube channel*?
(the best variant - is to validate using regexp)

Thanks.

Comment: SO is not a *write my code* service. You should provide a specific problem that you are facing as well as the code that if causing the problem. You didn't show any of your efforts to solve the problem. Nor did you provide a clear question as a person would now have to search what youtube specific links look line.

Comment: To make it clearer how to make your question more SO acceptable - give us a list of links you want matched and a list of links you don't want matched. Show us a regex you tried to use for said matching and tell us in what cases it failed.

Comment: @stribizhev now question looks good. if you cannot help me and don't know answer - please, go away from my question. I don't need your advises if it's off topic. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following Regex should ensure that the name matches [Google's name guidelines](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33386?hl=en): [-.'_-[:alnum:]]{6,20}

Comment: I am not aware of the exact limitations for channel URLs. If you provide me with them, I'd gladly get you a Regex for it.